# Saving multiple checkbox value to database

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework

I have a form where I have checkboxes and I want to send it to an API in order to save it to a database.

This is the **city.page.html**

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let city of cities;">
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="city.id" ></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label>{{city.name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-button type="button" (click)="saveCity()">Save</ion-button>
```

This is the **city.page.ts**

```js
city: any;

saveCity() {

    let data = {city: this.city};

    this.http.post('http://example.com/api/saveCity', JSON.stringify(data))
    .subscribe((res: any) => {console.log("success");});
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to send that data in the below format because the API only accepts this format to save it into the database.

```json
"city": [
    "32",
    "432",
    "231"
]
```

Any help to make it possible will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a couple of choices. First, you can add/remove city ids into an array on your component when clicked. Second, you can use a form array.

Comment: @Brandon I did the above steps that I posted, but unfortunately in the Chrome console, I get *undefined* response. I would be happy to post the correct format and answer to me and all those who have the same problem :).

Comment: You shouldn't need to stringify the data object. You would need to add your complete component code to your answer, but I wouldn't use ngModel to hold the selected checkbox values. Also, don't use `any` as your type. That's just setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: hmmm. That is tricky as I only know how to save the input values. I would be happy if you code it :). Thank you.

Comment: Um, yeah, that's not how this works. I can point out errors in your approach, but Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Google stackoverflow and found out ‘A public platform building the definitive collection of coding questions & answers ... A community-based space to find and contribute answers to technical..’.

Comment: Anyways, I will try to work with your comments and will keep you updated.

Comment: If you follow either approach in my first comment, you'll end up with an array of city ids that you can pass to your service call. If you're still having trouble, post your progress here and we can work through it.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this solution i don't know it is the best solution, maybe you could do in a more fancy way , but its works and solve your problem:

First on city.page.html, change the model and bind to a new one that will save the state of individual checkbox of the list , then add the value tag

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let city of cities;">
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedCities[city.id]"  value="city.id"></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>{{city.name}}</ion-label>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-button type="button" (click)="saveCity()">Save</ion-button>
```

then in cites.page.ts , just add a new property that will manage the states of the checkboxs:

```
selectedCities = {};
```

and then in your save method do this, you will filter the object keys that only have true(selected ones) and you will obtein the selected options as array:

```
    saveCity() {
      console.log(this.selectedCities);
      const array = Object.keys(this.selectedCities).filter((key)=> {return this.selectedCities[key]});
      console.log(array);
    }
```

that's all , have a great day dude xD

link to working demo [demo link](https://ionic-k8svmg.stackblitz.io/) , link to edit mode [demo link edition mode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-k8svmg)

Comment: I would prefer to use ReacttiveForms instead of using ngModel it will e better

Comment: @altoqueperro It worked perfectly. But I have another form that is not a checkbox. Can you please check it as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672945/getting-form-data-like-array-in-typescript-file