# Getting form data like array in typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a form and want to pass the form inputs into a typescript file as an array in ionic.

The form in **question.page.html**

```
<details *ngFor="let product of products;">

    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="productId" value="{{product.id}}"></ion-input>

    <h2>Question</h2>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="question"></ion-input>

    <h2>Contact Back</h2>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="contactBack" interface="popover">
       <ion-select-option value="0">No</ion-select-option>
       <ion-select-option value="1">Yes</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>

</details>

<ion-button type="button" (click)="sendQuestion()">Send Question</ion-button>
```

I want to show the result in a typescript file (**question.page.ts**) as below:

```
"productQuestions": [
    {
        //First
        'productId': 'value',
        'question': 'value',
        'contactBack': 'value',
    },
    {
        //Second
        'productId': 'value',
        'question': 'value',
        'contactBack': 'value',
    },
    ...
],
```

I know how to do it for a form that has fields that don't repeat, but I don't know how to do it for forms that repeat the same inputs multiple times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Reactive Forms.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib no. It is simple angular form.

Comment: You can bind the ngModel with product.id and product.question. Or use reactive forms

Comment: @AmmarHussain Thank you. But I can't bind as I am new to ionic and angular.

Comment: Reactive Forms are FORMS for Angular Application. They are use to make dynamic forms with complex data or repeated keys. Search it on google.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I searched a lot and used multiple StackOverflow answers but there are answers for one field that repeats, unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution where three fields are mentioned which are repeating.

Comment: You can check this tuto : https://www.positronx.io/ionic-form-validation-tutorial/ to master reactive-forms with ionic and angular

Comment: @RebaiAhmed the form doesn't use ngFor. I mean it is a static form and doesn't have repeated fields with the same name.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Any Idea!

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Any idea!

Comment: Juts you can use patchValue without ngFor in HTML to have completed form with filled fields

Comment: @RebaiAhmed can you please code it. If possible for you. As I am new I can't understand your comment.

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I didn't get any response yet.

Comment: Hi, you can check this tuto : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields

Comment: Hi @RebaiAhmed I tried this and it is for appending new fields to the form not saving nor sending the form data to the TS to show as an array. My question is that how can I send a from with 10 or more similar fields to the TS file as an array as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can bind model.

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.productId" value="{{product.id}}"></ion-input>

<h2>Question</h2>
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.question"></ion-input>

<h2>Contact Back</h2>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="product.contactBack" interface="popover">
   <ion-select-option value="0">No</ion-select-option>
   <ion-select-option value="1">Yes</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

```
<ion-button type="button" (click)="sendQuestion()">Send Question</ion-button>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will it work with ***ngFor="let product of products;"** because have then 12 products and they will load and each of them will have *question* and *contact back* fields.

Comment: I pasted your answer in the *html* file and what should I write in the *ts* file.

Comment: you dont need to write anything in .ts file. it will directly update your `products` array.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib when I do *console.log(products)* then it shows the list of the products that called from database and doesn't show the values which I added into the form.

Comment: it will update your previous values.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib yes it shows exact product lists but it doesn't show the **question** field value and the **contactBack** field value which I entered.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib did you see what I want in the ts file. I want to show the entered details in the HTML to be shown as array in ts file.

Comment: @Ammar-hussain I did as you said, but in TS file each product id is shown and the value of that input in front of it like: **product_id:22**, **product_id:33** . I want something like: **name of the input:value of the input**